# How to fix [::1] refused to connect error showed after submitting form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am building blog using codeigniter, i have a problem i.e "How to fix [::1] refused to connect error" that came after submitting form .  I tried my best but its not working. Help me how to fix it?

Login controller

```
<?php

class Login_c extends MY_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->helper('url')
        $this->load->view('public/admin_login_v');
    }

    public function admin_login() {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url')
        echo "Admin login page is reached ";


    }
```

admin_login_v

```
<div>
        <?php echo form_open('login_c/admin_login') ?>

    <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'username','placeholder'=>'Username'])?>
    <?php echo form_password( ['name'=>'password', 'placeholder'=>'password']) ?>

    <?php echo form_reset(['name'=>'cancel', 'value'=>'Cancel']),
          form_submit(['name'=>'login', 'value'=>'Login']) ?>
    </div>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/vi_Blog';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Database config file

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'ci_blog',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysql',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: If its coming from the database, the database doesn't listen on IPv6

Comment: @Vickel i have added .htaccess and config code. check plz

Comment: @LarsStegelitz if you plz check again my `admin_login` function, u would know that i m just echo a string not saving data into database. What u think is this still a database connection error?

Comment: Codeigniter has an db autoconnect feature.. check if it's enabled

Comment: check also the post #6 in this forum: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-67415-post-362641.html#pid362641

Comment: @LarsStegelitz i enabled it by adding 'database' in libraries array in autoload.php but still not connecting. now its showing only **localhost refused to connect**

Comment: show the database config (without your credentials, obviously) and try using a trailing '/' in your base_url()

Comment: try '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost' for the connection

Comment: @Vickel chk plz i have updated my question

Comment: @LarsStegelitz not working

Comment: what CI version? `$query_builder = TRUE;` is for 3.x, CI 2.x used `$active_record = TRUE;` And try `'db_debug' => true`

Comment: @Vickel CI   v3.1.9

Comment: last thing which comes in my mind, does your localhost have cpanel? if yes, try to open the database from cpanel. check if you have added a user for the database

Comment: @Vickel  no cpanel and database is empty

Comment: @Vickel thanks buddy for investing your precious time on me

Comment: no problem, I like resolving things :) did you try the forum link?

Comment: did you removed index.php to your config?

Comment: @curiosity sorry i m  not getting your point. could you please tell  me how to do that?

Comment: i mean if you are using .htacces you should remove index.php from $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; and leave it blank.

Comment: @curiosity using wamp instead of xampp solved my all problems. Thanks to all